# Time intervals overlapping with MySQL

Tags: mysql, intervals, date-range

I'm trying to create **booking system with multiple resources**: Calendar#1 and Calendar#2. Calendars do not contain overlapping ranges itself. Range in one calendar can span multiple ranges in the other one.

See the schema and data below or on [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/444be/2)

```
    Events on Calendar #1
        ID  startDate               endDate
        -----------------------------------------------
        1   2012-01-01 02:00:00     2012-01-01 03:00:00
        2   2012-01-01 05:00:00     2012-01-01 07:00:00
        3   2012-01-01 09:00:00     2012-01-01 11:00:00
        4   2012-01-01 16:00:00     2012-01-01 18:00:00
        5   2012-01-01 19:00:00     2012-01-01 22:00:00

        6   2012-02-02 10:00:00     2012-02-02 20:00:00

        7   2012-03-03 05:00:00     2012-03-03 07:00:00
        8   2012-03-03 09:00:00     2012-03-03 11:00:00
        9   2012-03-03 12:00:00     2012-03-03 14:00:00
        10  2012-03-03 15:00:00     2012-03-03 17:00:00
        11  2012-03-03 19:00:00     2012-03-03 21:00:00
        12  2012-03-03 22:00:00     2012-03-03 23:00:00

    Events on Calendar #2
        ID  startDate               endDate
        -----------------------------------------------
        1   2012-01-01 01:00:00     2012-01-01 04:00:00
        2   2012-01-01 06:00:00     2012-01-01 08:00:00
        3   2012-01-01 12:00:00     2012-01-01 14:00:00
        4   2012-01-01 15:00:00     2012-01-01 17:00:00
        5   2012-01-01 20:00:00     2012-01-01 21:00:00

        6   2012-02-02 05:00:00     2012-02-02 07:00:00
        7   2012-02-02 09:00:00     2012-02-02 11:00:00
        8   2012-02-02 12:00:00     2012-02-02 14:00:00
        9   2012-02-02 15:00:00     2012-02-02 17:00:00
        10  2012-02-02 19:00:00     2012-02-02 21:00:00
        11  2012-02-02 22:00:00     2012-02-02 23:00:00

        12  2012-03-03 10:00:00     2012-03-03 20:00:00


2012-01-01:
            0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0  1  2  3 
    Cal#1         |--|     |-----|     |-----|              |-----|  |--------|
    Cal#2      |--------|     |-----|           |-----|  |-----|        |--|

2012-02-02:
            0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0  1  2  3 
    Cal#1                                 |-----------------------------|
    Cal#2                  |-----|     |-----|  |-----|  |-----|     |-----|  |--|

2012-03-03:
            0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0  1  2  3 
    Cal#1                  |-----|     |-----|  |-----|  |-----|     |-----|  |--|
    Cal#2                                 |-----------------------------|
```

a) How to get intervals found **in both of calendars**:

```
             startDate               endDate
             -----------------------------------------------
             2012-01-01 02:00:00     2012-01-01 03:00:00
             2012-01-01 06:00:00     2012-01-01 07:00:00
             2012-01-01 16:00:00     2012-01-01 17:00:00
             2012-01-01 20:00:00     2012-01-01 21:00:00

             2012-02-02 10:00:00     2012-02-02 11:00:00
             2012-02-02 12:00:00     2012-02-02 14:00:00
             2012-02-02 15:00:00     2012-02-02 17:00:00
             2012-02-02 19:00:00     2012-02-02 20:00:00

             2012-02-03 10:00:00     2012-02-03 11:00:00
             2012-02-03 12:00:00     2012-02-03 14:00:00
             2012-02-03 15:00:00     2012-02-03 17:00:00
             2012-02-03 19:00:00     2012-02-03 20:00:00

            0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0  1  2  3 
01  Cal#1&2       |--|        |--|                          |--|        |--|
02  Cal#1&2                               |--|  |-----|  |-----|     |--|
03  Cal#1&2                               |--|  |-----|  |-----|     |--|
```

b) How to get intervals found **in #1 but not in #2**:

```
             startDate               endDate
             -----------------------------------------------
             2012-01-01 05:00:00     2012-01-01 06:00:00
             2012-01-01 09:00:00     2012-01-01 11:00:00
             2012-01-01 17:00:00     2012-01-01 18:00:00
             2012-01-01 19:00:00     2012-01-01 20:00:00
             2012-01-01 21:00:00     2012-01-01 22:00:00

             2012-02-02 11:00:00     2012-02-02 12:00:00
             2012-02-02 14:00:00     2012-02-02 15:00:00
             2012-02-02 17:00:00     2012-02-02 19:00:00

             2012-03-03 05:00:00     2012-03-03 07:00:00
             2012-03-03 09:00:00     2012-03-03 10:00:00
             2012-03-03 20:00:00     2012-03-03 21:00:00
             2012-03-03 22:00:00     2012-03-03 23:00:00

            0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0  1  2  3 
01  Cal#1-2                |--|        |-----|                 |--|  |--|  |--|
02  Cal#1-2                                  |--|     |--|     |-----| 
03  Cal#1-2                |-----|     |--|                             |--|  |--|
```

c) How to get intervals found in **none of the calendars** between START and END anywhere inside or outside calendar/interval ranges.

```
             startDate               endDate
             -----------------------------------------------
       START:2012-01-01 04:30:00     2012-01-01 05:00:00
             2012-01-01 08:00:00     2012-01-01 09:00:00
             2012-01-01 11:00:00     2012-01-01 12:00:00
             2012-01-01 14:00:00     2012-01-01 15:00:00
             2012-01-01 18:00:00     2012-01-01 19:00:00
             2012-01-01 22:00:00     2012-02-02 05:00:00
             2012-02-02 07:00:00     2012-02-02 09:00:00
             2012-02-02 21:00:00     2012-02-02 22:00:00
             2012-02-02 23:00:00     2012-03-03 05:00:00
             2012-03-03 07:00:00 END:2012-03-03 07:30:00

            0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0  1  2  3 
01  Cal-1-2              |-|        |--|     |--|     |--|        |--|        |------
02  Cal-1-2 ---------------|     |-----|                                   |--|  |---
03  Cal-1-2 ---------------|     |-END
```

Comment: Please provide some information on [what you have tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com).

Comment: Might a calendar itself contain overlapping ranges?  And/or might a range in one calendar span multiple ranges in the other?

Comment: Might a calendar range overlap the `START` and `END` boundaries in query `c`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. > How to get intervals found **in both of calendars**:

   ```
   SELECT GREATEST(Cal1.startDate, Cal2.startDate) AS startDate,
             LEAST(Cal1.endDate  , Cal2.endDate  ) AS   endDate
   FROM   Cal1 JOIN Cal2
       ON Cal2.startDate BETWEEN Cal1.startDate AND Cal1.endDate
       OR Cal1.startDate BETWEEN Cal2.startDate AND Cal2.endDate
   ```
2. > How to get intervals found **in #1 but not in #2**:

   ```
     SELECT Cal1.startDate, Cal2.startDate AS endDate
     FROM   Cal1 JOIN Cal2
         ON Cal2.startDate BETWEEN Cal1.startDate AND Cal1.endDate
   UNION ALL
     SELECT Cal2.endDate AS startDate, Cal1.endDate
     FROM   Cal1 JOIN Cal2
         ON Cal2.endDate   BETWEEN Cal1.startDate AND Cal1.endDate
   UNION ALL
     SELECT Cal1.startDate, Cal1.endDate
     FROM   Cal1 LEFT JOIN Cal2
         ON Cal2.startDate BETWEEN Cal1.startDate AND Cal1.endDate
         OR Cal1.startDate BETWEEN Cal2.startDate AND Cal2.endDate
     WHERE  Cal2.ID IS NULL
   ORDER BY startDate
   ```
3. > How to get intervals found in **none of the calendars** between START and END:

   ```
   SELECT   starts.d AS startDate, MIN(ends.d) AS endDate
   FROM (
     SELECT @start AS d
   UNION
     SELECT Cal1.endDate
     FROM   Cal1 LEFT JOIN Cal2
         ON Cal1.endDate BETWEEN Cal2.startDate AND Cal2.endDate
     WHERE  Cal1.endDate BETWEEN @start AND @end
        AND Cal2.ID IS NULL
   UNION
     SELECT Cal2.endDate
     FROM   Cal1 RIGHT JOIN Cal2
         ON Cal2.endDate BETWEEN Cal1.startDate AND Cal1.endDate
     WHERE  Cal2.endDate BETWEEN @start AND @end
        AND Cal1.ID IS NULL
   ) starts JOIN (
     SELECT @end AS d
   UNION
     SELECT Cal1.startDate
     FROM   Cal1 LEFT JOIN Cal2
         ON Cal1.startDate BETWEEN Cal2.startDate AND Cal2.endDate
     WHERE  Cal1.startDate BETWEEN @start AND @end
        AND Cal2.ID IS NULL
   UNION
     SELECT Cal2.startDate
     FROM   Cal1 RIGHT JOIN Cal2
         ON Cal2.startDate BETWEEN Cal1.startDate AND Cal1.endDate
     WHERE  Cal2.startDate BETWEEN @start AND @end
        AND Cal1.ID IS NULL
   ) ends ON starts.d < ends.d
   GROUP BY startDate
   ```

See them on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/40ec2/1).

Comment: No, calendars do not contain overlapping ranges itself. Range in one calendar can span multiple ranges in the other one. The `START` and `END` boundaries in query `c` might be anywhere - before, after or within any calendar interval.

Comment: I would be grateful for the updated solution. The `b` query doesn't work when one calendar span multiple ranges in the other one.

Comment: Can you not adapt the approach taken in the `c` query?